# Q: Root user invalid for ssh on alpine linux

Tags: ssh, docker, root, sshd, alpine-linux

**tl;dr:** The root user of alpine linux 3.9.4 is invalid for ssh unless setting a password. Why?

I'm having an odd behavior with ssh and the plain root user of linux alpine.

## Setup

I have created an ssh-hop docker container.

```
FROM alpine

# add openssh and clean
RUN apk add --update openssh \
    && rm  -rf /tmp/* /var/cache/apk/*

# copy sshd config
COPY docker/sshd_config /etc/ssh/

# copy entrypoint script
COPY docker/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin

# copy root SSH key
COPY docker/keys/root/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

# copy host identification keys
COPY docker/keys/host /etc/ssh

EXPOSE 22
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]
```

The mentioned `sshd_config`:

```
Port 22
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
LogLevel VERBOSE
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

And the `docker-entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

#prepare run dir
if [ ! -d "/var/run/sshd" ]; then
  mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
fi

echo "Starting sshd"

exec "$@"
```

The appropriate keys are generated before building the docker container via:

```
echo "Generating root rsa key pair"
ssh-keygen -f docker/keys/root/id_rsa -N '' -t rsa -b 4096
echo "Generating host rsa key pair"
ssh-keygen -f docker/keys/host/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa -b 4096
echo "Generating host ecdsa key pair"
ssh-keygen -f docker/keys/host/ssh_host_ecdsa_key -N '' -t ecdsa
echo "Generating host ecdsa key pair"
ssh-keygen -f docker/keys/host/ssh_host_ed25519_key -N '' -t ed25519
```

## Problem

If I build the Dockerfile under Ubuntu Server 18.04 with Docker Engine 18.09.6 and alpine linux version 3.9.4 and try to ssh into the container with `ssh root@127.0.0.1 -i docker/keys/root/id_rsa`, I get the error `ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused`. That was not the case with alpine linux version 3.8.1

### Solution

I have figured out that as soon as setting a password for the root user (which the user does not have in plain alpine) sshing into the server works as expected.
Thus as a solution is adding `RUN echo "root:root" | chpasswd` to the Dockerfile.

## Question

In the server logs sshd states `userauth_pubkey: disabled because of invalid user [preauth]`. Why is the root user invalid for sshd unless setting a password?

Git repo with the whole setup: https://github.com/JSPRH/sshd-docker/tree/c7fdef446b37484589cac546e9192a37440327a7